# Remove exception No entity found for query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use this code to make SQL request to find DB record:

```
public Optional<Subscription> findSubscriptionsByUserEmail(String email) {
        String hql = "SELECT s " +
                "FROM " + Subscription.class.getName() + " s " +
                "INNER JOIN " + Orders.class.getName() + " o  ON s.orderId = o.id " +
                "INNER JOIN " + Users.class.getName() + " u ON u.id = o.userId " +
                "WHERE u.email = :email " +
                "ORDER BY s.createdAt DESC ";
        TypedQuery<Subscription> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Subscription.class).setMaxResults(1).setParameter("email", email);
        Optional<Subscription> subscription = Optional.of(query.getSingleResult());
        return subscription;
    }
```

But when I don't have a record I get exception: `No entity found for query`
Do you know how I can skip this exception and continue code execution?

Comment: Why don't you wrap it inside a `try/catch` block and when there is no result, return `null` or whatever you want to be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is either to `try/catch` the optional object to see there has been a data sent back or make simple check to see if the optional has an object in it.

Eg:

```
!subscription.isPresent()? null:subscription;
```